# UITextField do not display datePicker.date as inputview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uidatepicker

When you tap `dateTextField` on `tableViewCell`, it shows `datePicker`.
you select date from `datePicker`.
But `dateTextField.text` do not display `datePicker.date`.

How do I fix it?

I have following code.

tableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    tableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if( cell == nil )
    {
        cell = [[tableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDateFormatter* outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString* dateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:cell.datePicker.date];
    cell.dateTextField.text = dateString;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.dateTextField];

    return cell;
}
```

tableViewCell.m

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField* dateTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDatePicker* datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar* toolBar;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 320, 40)];
    self.toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:)];
    NSArray* barItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil];
    [self.toolBar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    self.dateTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 5, 100, 25)];
    self.dateTextField.delegate = self;
    self.dateTextField.inputView = self.datePicker;
    self.dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolBar;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dateTextField];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.dateTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't very clear (there seems to be other important parts missing), but I believe the proper way to do this is to grab the date from the date picker after the user presses done (notified by IBAction), and then custom format it and set the textField's string to your format string. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding `setText` method.
fixed code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField* dateTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDatePicker* datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar* toolBar;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 320, 40)];
    self.toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:)];
    NSArray* barItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil];
    [self.toolBar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    self.dateTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 5, 100, 25)];
    self.dateTextField.delegate = self;
    self.dateTextField.inputView = self.datePicker;
    self.dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolBar;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dateTextField];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSDateFormatter* outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString* dateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    [self.dateTextField setText:dateString];
    [self.dateTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```